# PHP Mailer SMTP ERROR Command Failed

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

I've been having some troubles trying to setup PHP Mailer. 
I keep getting this error. I've disabled and enabled the extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini. I've enabled Access for less secure apps, turned on imap and still nothing.

```
2017-05-05 09:33:09     SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP v7sm1232085wme.5 - gsmtp
2017-05-05 09:33:09     CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO Gonþalo-PC
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SERVER -> CLIENT: 501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "Gonþalo-PC" invalid, closing connection.
                                          501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo v7sm1232085wme.5 - gsmtp
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "Gonþalo-PC" invalid, closing conn
ection.
                                          501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo v7sm1232085wme.5 - gsmtp
2017-05-05 09:33:10     CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO Gonþalo-PC
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SERVER -> CLIENT:
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed:
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-05-05 09:33:10     SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I'm using XAMPP V.3.2.2 , PHP 7.1.2 , COMPOSER 5.2.

here's my code

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'buscar_lembretes.php';


$lembretes = buscarLembretes();


foreach ($lembretes as $lembrete) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'Lembrestes App');
    $mail->addAddress($lembrete['email'], $lembrete['email']);
    $mail->Subject = 'Lembrete';
    $mail->Body = $lembrete['descricao'];
    $mail->send();

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a setting in your php.ini, or a local hostname being used for the HELO string. What you have in there is not valid for SMTP, which only handles 7-bit data at that point. You can override this by setting the `Hostname` property to whatever the name of your host is, for example:

```
$mail->Hostname = 'myserver.example.com';
```

Note that this is distinct from the `Host` property which is the address of the server you are connecting *to*.